# Render PDF with PhantomJS and send to user without creating temporary file

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I'm trying to render PDF document with PhantomJS and send to user but without creating any files in the process. The reason for that is security, if I don't store any files there is nothing to be stolen. What I tried to do is to instead of running "page.render(filePath, cb)" I do "page.renderBase64('PNG', cb)" and that would be fine except all footers and headers with page num etc are gone (when I just render PDF file they are there)

Is there some way to make those footers/headers render or to accomplish my task differently?

EDIT:
Sorry, I've posted this question at around 5am my time after hours of fight and I simply forgot to add code which I guess might be useful. Code commented out works perfectly fine and generates the file that I would expect with footers and headers. My version of PhantomJS is 2.0.0

```
return P.coroutine(function* () {
  var result = yield getPhantom();
  result.page.set('content', template);

  var options = {
    format: 'Letter',
    paperSize: {width: '215.9mm', height: '279.4mm'},
    margin: {
      left: '25.4mm',
      right: '25.4mm',
      top: '25.4mm',
      bottom: '25.4mm'
    }
  };

  if (document.metadata && document.metadata.enableHeader) {
    options.header = {
      height: '30px',
      contents: result.ph.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
        return '<div style="pull-right; font-size: 10px;">Page ' + pageNum + ' of ' + numPages + '</div>';
      })
    }
  }
  if (document.metadata && document.metadata.enableFooter) {
    var footerTemplate = document.footer ?
      document.footer : yield fs.readFile(path.join(templatesPath, 'footer.hbs'), 'utf8');
    var footer = Handlebars.compile(footerTemplate)({
      data: data,
      metadata: document.metadata
    });
    var returnFooter = new Function('pageNum', 'numPages', `return '${footer.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')}'`);
    options.footer = {
      height: document.metadata.footerHeight || '120px',
      contents: result.ph.callback(returnFooter)
    }
  }

  result.page.set('paperSize', options);

  //var filePath = path.join(tmpPath, fileService.randomName() + '.pdf');

  var base64 = yield P.fromNode((cb) => result.page.renderBase64('PNG', cb.bind(null, null)));
  //yield P.fromNode(function (cb) {
  //  result.page.render(filePath, cb);
  //});
  result.ph.exit();
  return base64;
  //return filePath;
})();
}
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version are you using? You didn't by any chance set crop settings?